# How decode ascii to russian characters?

Tags: decode

I have this ASCII:

208 165 208 176 209 134 208 186 32 208 176 209 130 209 133 208 190 208 189 32 208 176 208 187 32 209 130 208 181 209 128 208 180 208 176 209 130 32 208 176 32 45 32 208 181 209 129 209 130 208 190 32 209 131 32 208 180 208 181 208 189 209 130 209 128 208 190 33

And need to decode to russian. I'm only get something like: ХацкBQ�[.[LQ�Q}�1l2�тердатBQ��BQ,[$[.Q�ܑ�дентро!

How i can get the right message ?

I'm using this site: http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/

Comment: That's not ASCII because ASCII code units are 0 to 127. Which character encoding is it? Are you sure the entire sequence of bytes represent text?

Comment: Hello! I dont know the enconding :/ I need to decode this units to text

Comment: No one can tell you the encoding except the person who sends it to you. If you receive it through HTTP, a Content-Type header might be the way you are being told. If you don't have the bytes and the encoding then you don't have the text; you have data loss.

Comment: If you want to guess, 437 and ISO 8859-1 are always valid so you'd have to rule them out in other ways. If it's valid as UTF-8, consider that, too. There are hundreds of encodings. Many might be valid, some might be valid and decode to the same text as another, only one is correct: the one that was used to encode the text.